# sql query to avoid null value parameter

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

these are the variables i am passing to some method where i need to write some sql query like

```
string cmd = @"select *
from students_tbl
where
     course_id=@courseId and branch_id=in(+" branchId "+)
and passout_year>=@passoutYear
and current_backlog>=@currentBacklog
and gender=@gender
and eGap<=@eGap
and first_year_percent>=@firstyearPercent
and second_year_percent>=@seconYearPercent
and third_year_percent>=@thirdyearPercent";
```

and so on but problem is that few of these parameters are optional means for those variable 
there value is null so i don't want to include those parameter in query 
so how should i eliminate those null variable i am not getting how should i write query to solve this issue

those parameter are random nothing fix when they will be null because hey are optional
so how should i write query by using only not null parameter

Comment: those paameter are random nothing fix when they will be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `is null` check before your comparison, which will short-circuit if the input parameter value is `null`, e.g.:

```
where (@currentBacklog is null or current_backlog >= @currentBacklog)
```

Comment: if i put IS NULL like you did then that parameter would not be taken in account? that's what i want please let me know

Comment: i am afraid that you didn't understand me
it may sound rude but from the above code what i figure out htat it would look for those value in the data base which are null for current backlog or greater than the @currentBacklog 
But is it true that by the above code it would not take current_backlog>=@currentbakclog in account i mean it will completey ignore it and filter it out then i wil run the query ?

Comment: i am not making stored procedure it's simple parametrized query

Comment: @Novice: That is incorrect, the above sample does not match records where current_backlog is null, rather, if the @currentBacklog **parameter** is null (i.e., not supplied, or supplied as `null`), then the condition will evaluate to true and the second clause `current_backlog >= @currentBacklog` will not be evaluated.

Comment: Hello sir when i applied the idea explained by you above it's not working for null it's giving the sql exception 
Parameterized Query '(@courseId int,@passoutYear int,@currentBacklog int,@sex int,@eG' expects parameter @currentDegeePercentage, which was not supplied.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for a null value in the condition, and use the value from the table instead. Example:

```
... where course_id = isnull(@courseId, course_id) ...
```

Comment: every time i need to check for not null parameter how can i do that?
I am not getting would you please put some code

Comment: i am not using stored procedure  i just want to know for simple parametrized query

Comment: u mean to say that every time i will have too check for null parameter value and then i will have to concatenate them

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: Just put the code in the query and the value in the parameter. If the value is null, the condition evaluates to `course_id = course_id` and you compare the field to itself, otherwise the condition evaluates to `course_id = @courseId`. As you can use the same code for both null and non-null values, you only need one version of the query regardless of which parameter values are null.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having

```
cmd = "one long string with many clauses, some of which are optional"
```

try

```
cmd = "first clause, required"
if second param is not null then
   cmd = cmd & "second clause, optional"
```